# only if chef code fails , error should be captured by ignore_failure_true and display error message

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

```
execute 'install_insatller' do
  cwd "abc"
  command reg_cmd
  ignore_failure true
  log 'STDERROR'
  only_if { ::File.exist?('abc') }
end
```

this is just an expample code 
I want to print the log message only if the failure occurs else continue the installation.

Answer (score 1):

`ignore_failure true` means that if there is an error, we show the usual error display but don't abort the converge. If you want behavior other than that, you'll probably have to write something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture output and take decission based on that then please use Mixlib shellout instead of execute.

`if ::File.exist?('abc')
        require 'mixlib/shellout'
        cmnd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(reg_cmd)
        cmnd.run_command
        if cmnd.error?
          puts cmnd.stderr
          else
          <write your code here to continue with installation>
        end
    end`